# A way to get run directory name

Tags: linux, bash

I can't understand the following code in a bash.

```
set `pwd` ; mfix=$1
```

It actually get the run directory name.But I don't how does it work.
What is the set command mean?

Answer (score 5):

From the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) for the `set`:

> This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section. set
>   allows you to change the values of shell options and **set the
>   positional parameters**, or to display the names and values of shell
>   variables.

e.g.

```
set v1 v2 v3 ; echo $1
```

will print

```
v1
```

The comand inside backticks is called as "command substitution". From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines deleted.

In your example, it **sets** the 1st positional argument `$1` to the value of the result of execution of command inside the backticks. (called as command substitution). The command is `pwd` what shows the current working directory.

Anyway, if the path to the directory contains an space, the `$1` will get only the first part of the path., e.g.

```
$ pwd
/some/path with/space
$ set `pwd`
$ echo $1
/some/path
$echo $2
with/space
```

Finally the all above is strange design, because you can simply:

```
mfix=$(pwd)   #old school:  mfix=`pwd`
```

It is better to use the `$(command)` instead of the backticks.

Comment: Hah! you have the same disease I do. (check 'simple' should be 'simply') at 3rd line from bottom beginning with **Finally**. It must be human nature to type 'simply' as 'simple'... If you sound out 'simple', e.g. 'simp-l-e' you get 'simply'. Who knows...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :) i'm happy, because I never learned english "oficially", but only from internet. Therefore I can read (and understand) nearly anything (I have a relatively good vocabulary), but don't understand to spoken english, don't know the right pronunciation - so can't speak, and finally, I can write _only_ some (badly stylised) text. ;) /Thanx - edited. :)/

Answer (score 2):

This code in bash put the result of the command `pwd` in the variable mfix.

You can print the result of the mfix variable by running

```
echo $mfix
```